# Why Google Maps render custom symbol pretty bad on retina?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have custom symbol (not icon file) for markers. It's vector, I think.

But when I open this on Macbook Pro Retina, I see artefacts, it looks like jpg.

My symbol:

```
icon:
  path: "M18.3,9.7c0,4.8-8.7,17.3-8.7,17.3S1,14.5,1,9.7C1,4.9,4.9,1,9.7,1C14.5,1,18.3,4.9,18.3,9.7z"
  fillColor: "#43A1DD"
  fillOpacity: 1
  strokeColor: "#FFFFFF"
  strokeWeight: 2
```

Rendering:

[image: JPG as fuck]

Answer (score 1):

What ends up for the browser to display, isn’t a vector graphic anymore. I inspected [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom) that draws a golden star using this code:

```
var goldStar = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeWeight: 14
};
```

Using JavaScript, the path is drawn on a canvas—which is pixel-based. That’s why it doesn’t look nice on Hi-DPI/retina screens.

[image: vector graphic rendered on canvas]